# How to redirect urls after deep level folder name change using rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, http-status-code-301, redirect

Our site spans across multiple languages (16 total), so the beginning of the url can contain 16 different subfolders. We have a subfolder beyond the lang/locale folder that has changed names so I am wondering how to redirect to the urls that involve the new subfolder name while also redirecting across the 16 different lang/locale subfolders?

Here is an example of the old and new urls:

Old urls:

www.something.com/en_US/product/family/parent/child.html
www.something.com/ru_RU/product/family/parent/child/model.html

New urls:

www.something.com/en_US/product/family/parent/child2.html
www.something.com/ru_RU/product/family/parent/child2/model.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2}_[a-zA-Z]{2})/product/family/parent/([\w_]+)\.html$ /${1}/product/family/parent/${2}2.html
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2}_[a-zA-Z]{2})/product/family/parent/([\w_]+)/([\w_]+)\.html$ /${1}/product/family/parent/${2}2/${3}.html
```

This may work for you, assuming that you're literally wanting to rename `child_folder` to `child_folder2` (`bikes` -> `bikes2`, `barbies` -> `barbies2`, etc).

If your goal is something more complicated (`bikes` -> `bicycles`, `barbies` -> `dolls`), that becomes something that needs to be handled through a server-side programming language, but htaccess can help. You can do something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2}_[a-zA-Z]{2})/product/family/parent/(child)\.html$ director.php?lang=${1}&old=${2}
```

But you should avoid doing this if a straight regex solution is appropriate because there's no need to involve both and increase the load on your server when one is already involved.